# Impala with Sas 9.4 : not import data with create table

Tags: sas, impala

creating a table with Sas and Impala I can't import data with many columns (more than 1500). The table is created but the data is not written and the following error is generated:

ERROR: CLI execute error: [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala:
   [HY000] : AnalysisException: Syntax         error in line 1: ...`,`xxx`)  VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ... 
    ^ Encountered:         Unexpected character Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER

Thank you

Comment: Ok. Provide more details, what were you trying to do more explicitly, move data from SAS to Impala or vice versa? What have you tried?

Comment: Only when i move data from SAS to Impala.

Comment: You need to provide more detailed information regarding your problem. Please see the guidelines on how to ask a question.

Comment: The table is created with SAS and Cloudera Impala ODBC engine. My table have more then 1500 columns and when I try to create a new tabele with SAS on Impala (via ODBC) return me the error ERROR: CLI execute error: [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) .
I've tried a Create table as select from an existing table in sas (work) or impala. Also I've tried the same create table as select with only one row and give me the same error. The ODBC driver used is the Cloudera Impala ODBC driver 2.5.32 and run on Linux CentOs.
Thank you

Comment: The limit is 1080 columns... after there's the error!

Answer (score 0):

I try to create a view or a table with engine SAS Impala (ODBC impala ClouderaImpalaODBC-2.5.36.1009-1.x86_64) RedHat 6.8. And I get this error:

ERROR: CLI execute error: [Cloudera] [ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala: [HY000]: AnalysisException: Syntax
        error in line 1: ... King ((a.`trns_dt` between {d '31.10.2015'} and {d '^ 2 ... Encountered:
        Unexpected character Expected: CASE, CAST, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT NULL, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER Caused BY:
        Exception: Syntax error

We have seen that characters that are passed impala can not read such. "{}".

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This is not a question. Please see related questions on the right if any of them can answer it, or create your new question. This is not a forum thread, answers are for answering the question only;